# Template for regex search

Tags: c++, regex, windows

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto RegexSearch(const std::basic_string<T>& str, 
                 const std::basic_string<T>& regex)
{
    using iter = typename std::basic_string<T>::const_iterator;
    std::basic_regex<T> re(regex);
    std::match_results<iter> m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, re);
    return m;
}

// call example
auto match = RegexSearch(L"[0,1,2,3]"s
    , LR"((\d+))"s);
```

Inside of the template scope, `m` stores correct values, but `auto match = RegexSearch(...)`

`match` contain only garbage, what's going on?

-Edit-

```
template <typename T>
auto RegexSearch(const std::basic_string<T>& str,
    const std::basic_string<T>& regex)
{
    using iter = typename std::basic_string<T>::const_iterator;
    std::basic_regex<T> re(regex);
    std::match_results<iter> m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, re);

    std::vector<std::basic_string<T>> match{};
    match.emplace_back(m[0]);
    match.emplace_back(m.prefix());
    match.emplace_back(m.suffix());
    return match;
}
```

`RegexSearch` will be always just 1 value returned correct?

Is it 'wrong' to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

`std::match_results<iter> m` uses iterators into the original string, whilst this is more efficient as it avoids copying the original string it does require the original string to still exist. `str` is initialised with a temporary string when you call `RegexSearch` so the iterators inside `match` are dangling when the temporary string is destroyed at the end of the line.

The simplest solution is to not use a temporary string:

```
auto str = L"[0,1,2,3]"s;
auto match = RegexSearch(str
        , LR"((\d+))"s);
```

Comment: How to return a 'copy' of m?

Comment: @Nathan there's not much you can do, `std::match_results` is fundamentally just a list of iterators, you have to give `regex_search` something that will have valid iterators for as long as you want `std::match_results` to be valid. Maybe you could change your function to return a vector of strings instead of `std::match_results`?

Comment: Take a look on my edited question, is it wrong do such thing?

Comment: Depends what you want to use it for